# Cocose2d-x ParticleSystemQuad extending never call destructor when setAutoRemoveOnFinish(true)

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

as i understand when imark the emitter with setAutoRemoveOnFinish(true)
it should remove the emitter and somehow trigger the CCParticleSystemQuad so if i extend the CCParticleSystemQuad 
it should call the extended CCParticleSystemQuad  class distracture what is not happening . 
this is my simple class

```
class CC_DLL ParticleFromFile : public ParticleSystemQuad
{
public:

    static ParticleFromFile* create(const std::string& filename);    
CC_CONSTRUCTOR_ACCESS:

    ParticleFromFile(const std::string& filename);

    virtual ~ParticleFromFile(); 

private:
    CC_DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(ParticleFromFile);
};

ParticleFromFile::ParticleFromFile(const std::string& filename) 

{
    ;
}

ParticleFromFile* ParticleFromFile::create(const std::string& filename)
{
    ParticleFromFile* ret = new ParticleFromFile(filename);

    if (ret->initWithFile(filename))
    {
        ret->autorelease();
    }
    else
    {
        CC_SAFE_DELETE(ret);
    }
    return ret;
}

ParticleFromFile::~ParticleFromFile()
{
    int stop =0;
}
```

and this is how i setup the emitter

```
 _emitterLocal = ParticleFromFile::create(stringPilstName);
                 _emitterLocal->setTag(EXPLOSION_FROM_FILE_TAG);
                 _emitterLocal->setAutoRemoveOnFinish(true);
                 _emitterLocal->retain();
                 _emitterLocal->stopSystem();
                 _emitterLocal->unscheduleUpdate();
                 _emitterLocal->scheduleUpdate();
```

and then i start it with

```
_emitterLocal->resetSystem();
```

now every thing is working fine and the particles working great , but it never removed / cleaned and the destructor  never called 
what do i miss here ?

Comment: Particle will remove after `Finish`, But When does it `Finish` ?

Comment: dono this is the question ,

Comment: Why did you `retain()`  before `stopSystem()` ? check out my answer. PS: I don't see any point in `unscheduleUpdate()` and `scheduleUpdate()`. What are they for ?!

Answer (score 0):

To remove a particle system You have 2+1 choices :

1. If your particle system have a **finite duration**, the best way is use `setAutoRemoveOnFinish(true)`. It will automatically remove the system from parent node when particle system ends. ( Finsih time is set with `setDuration()` )
2. If your particle system have a **infinite duration**, then use `removeChild()` with `cleanup=true`. This way the system is removed forced.
3. Or you can use `stopSystem()` with `setAutoRemoveOnFinish(true)`, and the system will be removed after the last particle ends (=lifespan of the last particle).